# ¿Cómo redirigir en redirectTo en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

estoy haciendo una página web, y quiero hacer que dependiendo de unas variables, al hacer login, se redirija a una página o a otra.
He estado haciendo pruebas, y es muy fácil si no se pasan parámetros, pero el problema es que para una de las opciones, he de enviarle atributos en en enlace.
Había puesto esto:

```
 protected function redirectTo()
    {

        $user = Auth::user();

        if($user->rol == 'superadmin'){

            return '/shops';
    
        }else if($user->restablished == 1) {

            
            $employer = DB::table('users')->where('dni', $user->dni)->first();

            return redirect()->route('EmployerEdit', ['employer' => $employer]);
    
        }else{

            return '/home';
        }
    }
```

Para la primera y la última opción, todo funciona correctamente, pero para la segunda opción me sale el siguiente error:

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

La primera opción había sido poner:

```
 return '/EmployerEdit/'+$employer->dni;
```

Pero si lo pongo así, me sale el siguiente error:

> A non-numeric value encountered

Y en web.xml, si que tengo la ruta definida:

```
Route::get('/EmployerEdit/{employer?}', [App\Http\Controllers\EmployerController::class, 'openEdit'])->name('EmployerEdit');
```

Y desde el fichero blade, con:

```
<a href={{ route('EmployerEdit', [$employer->dni])}} class="btn btn-primary">Editar empleado</a>
```

Si que accedo a la ventana deseada.

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna opción para usar el route del blade, en el cotroller, o como poder acceder a esa ruta desde el controller del login.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Esto `return '/EmployerEdit/'+$employer->dni;` no sé si funciona, en php creo que se concatena con un punto `.`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ correcto, no funcionaria porque al poner el `+` se interpreta como suma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

desde luego que en PHP se concatena con el punto .  y se suma con el mas +

seria interesante saber que datos del usuario tienes almacenados en el objeto `$user`,
para ver como esta almacenada la propiedad dni que es a la que quieres acceder cuando la llamas, `$user->dni`. Puedes introducir en tu código la función dd() para ello antes de realizar la consulta, por que el error te dice que `$user->dni` es un objeto que no puede convertirse a string.

```
dd($user, $user->dni);//imprimirá en pantalla las variables y detiene el script.

$employer = DB::table('users')->where('dni', $user->dni)->first();
```